# OpenOffice.org: Regex - Skip first match

Tags: regex, openoffice.org

I have some misformatted phone numbers in a OpenOffice.org calc document which I want to fix.
The misformatted ones look like this:

```
555 / 28 / 2910 / 187 / 1
```

How they should look:

```
555 / 2829101871
```

My question now is: How can I remove every slash in a cell but leave the first one?

Answer (score 2):

This will select the bold part: 555 / (**28 / 2910 / 187 / 1**):

```
[^\/]+\/ (.*)
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/hD9aT9)

And if you want to select the **three** slash with the **spaces** on the right only: 555 / 28( / )2910( / )187( / )1

```
[^\/]+\/ [^\/]+( \/ )[^\/]+( \/ )[^\/]+( \/ )
```

**[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vV1cN3)**

Answer (score 0):

VBAScript does not support lookbehind. Neither, as far as I know, does it support replace callbacks, otherwise we could use the method in this question to ["regex-match a pattern unless..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174) to do something like:

```
Dim myRegExp, replaced
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "^[^ /]* / |( / )"
replaced = myRegExp.Replace(SubjectString, 
     // some function that only replaces the match if Group 1 is set.
                            )
```

As far as I can see, this leaves us with a three-step solution:

1. Replace the first one with something distinctive
2. Replace the other ones
3. Replace the first one again

**1. Replacing the first one:**

Search: `^([^ /]*) /`

Replace: `$1@@DISTINCTIVE@@`

Some code:

```
Dim myRegExp, replaced
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "^([^ /]*) / "
replaced = myRegExp.Replace(SubjectString, "$1@@DISTINCTIVE@@")
```

**2. Replacing the other ones:**

Search: `/`, Replace: `""`

**3. Restoring the first one:**

Search: `@@DISTINCTIVE@@`, Replace: `/`